# Ajax and jQuery combining sorting and searching

Tags: jquery, ajax, search

I have created a searching system and a sorting system that both work individually. How would I go about getting them both to work on the same query on the same page, if there is are better strategies for better systems I'm all ears.

Here is the sorting system

```
<?php  
 //lagra.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'fiberdb');  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM skickform ORDER BY form_id DESC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>  
      <body>  
      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
    </div>
   </div>
           <br />            


                <div class="table-responsive" id="skickform">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th><a class="column_sort" id="form_id" data-order="desc" href="#">ID</a></th>  
                               <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickLE" data-order="desc" href="#">Levrantör</a></th>  
                               <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickHH" data-order="desc" href="#">Hastighet</a></th>  
                               <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickAT" data-order="desc" href="#">Avtalstid</a></th>  
                               <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickGA" data-order="desc" href="#">Gatuadress</a></th>
                               <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickKN" data-order="desc" href="#">Kundnamn</a></th>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                          ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["form_id"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["skickLE"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["skickHH"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["skickAT"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["skickGA"]; ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row["skickKN"]; ?></td>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  

           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

second part

```
 <?php  
 //sort.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fiberdb");  
 $output = '';  
 $order = $_POST["order"];  
 if($order == 'desc')  
 {  
      $order = 'asc';  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      $order = 'desc';  
 } 
$query = "SELECT * FROM skickform ORDER BY ".$_POST["column_name"]." ".$_POST["order"]."";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$output .= '
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th><a class="column_sort" id="form_id" data-order="'.$order.'" href="#">ID</a></th>
                <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickLE" data-order="'.$order.'" href="#">Levrantör</a></th>
                <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickHH" data-order="'.$order.'" href="#">Hastighet</a></th>
                <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickAT" data-order="'.$order.'" href="#">Avtalstid</a></th>
                <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickGA" data-order="'.$order.'" href="#">Gatuadress</a></th>
                <th><a class="column_sort" id="skickKN" data-order="'.$order.'" href="#">Kundnamn</a></th>

            </tr>

            ';  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            {  
                 $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td>' . $row["form_id"] . '</td>  
                      <td>' . $row["skickLE"] . '</td>  
                      <td>' . $row["skickHH"] . '</td>  
                      <td>' . $row["skickAT"] . '</td>  
                      <td>' . $row["skickGA"] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row["skickKN"] . '</td>  
                 </tr>  
                 ';  
            }  
            $output .= '</table>';  
            echo $output;  
            ?>
```

here is the searching system

```
       <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
     <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
    </div>
   </div>
           <br />  



<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fiberdb");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM skickform 
  WHERE form_id LIKE '%".$search."%'
  OR skickLE LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR skickHH LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR skickAT LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR skickGA LIKE '%".$search."%' 
  OR skickKN LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
  SELECT * FROM skickform ORDER BY form_id
 ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
     <th>Levrantör</th>
     <th>Hastighet</th>
     <th>Avtalstid</th>
     <th>Gatuadress</th>
     <th>Kundnamn</th>
    </tr>
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["form_id"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["skickLE"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["skickHH"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["skickAT"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["skickGA"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["skickKN"].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

second part of searching system

```
 <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
          $(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function(){  
               var column_name = $(this).attr("id");  
               var order = $(this).data("order");  
               var arrow = '';  
               //glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up  
               //glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down  
               if(order == 'desc')  
               {  
                    arrow = '&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>';  
               }  
               else  
               {  
                    arrow = '&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>';  
               }  
               $.ajax({  
                    url:"sort.php",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:{column_name:column_name, order:order},  
                    success:function(data)  
                    {  
                         $('#skickform').html(data);  
                         $('#'+column_name+'').append(arrow);  
                    }  

               })  
          });  
     });  
     </script>  
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

     load_data();

     function load_data(query)
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"sort.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('#result').html(data);
       }
      });
     }
     $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
      var search = $(this).val();
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Is there a better way of doing this than using these 2 together?

I wasn't really thinking setting them up individually, I tried just setting the search script under the sorting script and that didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It uses jQuery and Bootstrap 3/4 if you want.
The main idea is:

- query your DB;
- create your HTML table;
- using jquery to run DataTables

js Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#yourTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to combine both querys, when you POST the data to your php script should send sort and search variables.

example:
Your HTML:

```
<a class="column_sort" id="form_id" data-order="ASC" href="#">ID</a></th>
<input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
```

Your Javascript:

Find if exist a selected sort columns and trigger the ajax function

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
    var selected = $('.selected');
    var column_name='',order='';
    if(selected.length>0){
        column_name = selected.attr("id");
        order = selected.data("order");
    }
    var query = $('#search_text').val()
    queryPost( column_name, order, query )
})
```

Set the selected sort columns and trigger the ajax function

```
$('.column_sort').on('click', function(){
    var selected = $(this);
    selected.addClass('selected')
    var column_name = selected.attr("id");
    var order = selected.data("order");
    var query = $('#search_text').val()
    queryPost( column_name, order, query )
});

function queryPost( column_name, order, query ){
    $.ajax({
        url:"sort.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{ query:query, column_name:column_name, order:order },
        success:function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

in sort.php you have to combine both querys and validate POST values...